# How to type the species pattern (overriding the default constructor with a static symbol property)

Tags: typescript

JS has a well-known symbol [`@@species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) used by `Array` and other types to [construct derivative types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Species). Is it possible to express the species pattern in TypeScript?

A simplified example:

```js
class Foo {
  static [Symbol.species] = Foo;
  bar() {
    return new this.constructor[Symbol.species]();
  }
}
```

The return type of the `Foo#bar()` method should be based on the `Foo` constructor's `Symbol.species` property, but I don't know how or if it's possible to reference symbol properties.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the closest thing to this would be use `this` as the retrun type `class Foo {
  static [Symbol.species] = Foo;
  bar() : this {
    return new this.constructor[Symbol.species]() as this;
  }
}`. this works if `bar` always returns the same type as the current type, but is definitely not a replacement

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Do you know if this is still true, 3 years later?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yup, as far as I know, this is still the case

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir & slikts: [This approach using `Object.getPrototypeOf` seems to work](https://tsplay.dev/w1PZKW), based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726950/return-new-self-equivalent-in-typescript-for-class-inheritance) posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328117/157247) (and sadly cross-posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328061/157247)).