# Create abstract class that has methods returning instance this

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an abstract class `ParseContent` that allows it's implementors to implement a `parse` method, the catch is that the `ParseContent` abstract class has other methods, that return instances of the inheriting class. is this possible?

```
export abstract class ParseContent extends RawContent { 
  parsed: any

  constructor(params: ConstructorParameters<typeof RawContent>[0] & {
    parsed: any
  }) {
    super(params)
    this.parsed = params.parsed
  }

  abstract parse<T> (content: string): T

  static fromString(opt: Parameters<typeof RawContent['fromString']>[0]) { 
    const pureOpts = super.fromStringOpts(opt)
    const parsed = this.parse(pureOpts.content)
    return new this({ ...pureOpts, parsed })
  }

  static async fromPath(opt: Parameters<typeof RawContent['fromPath']>[0]) { 
    const pureOpts = await super.fromPathOpts(opt)
    const parsed = this.parse(pureOpts.content)
    return new this({ ...pureOpts, parsed })
  }

}

export class JSONContent extends ParseContent { 
  static parse(content: string): any { 
    return JSON.parse(content)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is *what* possible?  *"that the ParseContent abstract class has other methods, that return instances of the inheriting class"* << this?

Comment: With a little bit of refactor, you could create an abstract method, for example `createOne`, and implement in your child classes, so you can replace `return new this(...)` by `return this.createOne()`. This could also help when you have an specific class with a completely different behaviour and attributes initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `new this` in your `static` members, they'll create instances of whatever class they're called on. For instance, calls to `JSONContent.fromPath(...)` (`JSONContent` inherits it from `ParseContent`, since `ParseContent` is the prototype of `JSONContent` — a feature fairly specific to JavaScript and TypeScript) will create a `JSONContent` instance, because during the call to `fromPath`, `this` is `JSONContent`. It will use the `parse` on `JSONContent` for the same reason: `this` is `JSONContent`.

Example:

```js
class Parent {
    static wrapper() {
        return this.create();
    }
    static create() {
        const ctor = (this && this[Symbol.species]) || this;
        return new ctor();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
}
console.log(Child.create() instanceof Child);  // true
console.log(Child.wrapper() instanceof Child); // true
```

You can give subclasses the ability to override that with the [species pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) (and probably others), but my sense of what you're asking is that you want the default behavior.

As for the TypeScript aspect of this, I'm afraid [the news may not be good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259120/how-to-type-the-species-pattern-overriding-the-default-constructor-with-a-stati).