# Return new self equivalent in TypeScript for class inheritance

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I have a base class `Collection` which provides basic array features. This class gets extended for other domain-specific use cases. When a "destructing" method like `filter` is called, it should return a new instance with the filtered elements (to continue making use of class methods instead of just getting the array back).

In PHP you'd use `return new self()` to return the actual child or parent class, based on what it was constructed on (I think for Java it's `return obj.newInstance()`). But with JS/TS I really struggle to find a solution to this. My current workaround is to overwrite the `newInstance` method by all child classes.

Is there a solution to this?

```js
class Collection<E> {
  protected items: E[];

  constructor(items: any[] = []) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  // doesn't work, just one of many attempts
  protected newInstance(items: E[]) {
    return new Collection(items);

    //return new this.constructor(items); // "This expression is not constructable"

    // return new this.constructor.prototype(items); // another attempt, says "this.constructor.prototype is not a constructor"
  }

  size() {
    return this.items.length;
  }

  // should filter and return new instance to use class methods
  filter(callback: (item: any, index?: number) => boolean): this {
    // should be the actual instance (can be inherited)
    return this.newInstance(this.items.filter(callback)) as this;
  }
}

class NumberCollection extends Collection<number> {
  sum() {
    return this.items.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }
}

let numbers = new NumberCollection([1, 2, 3, 4]);

console.log(numbers.sum()); // works,

// throws "sum() is not a function"
console.log(numbers.filter((n) => n > 1).sum());
```

Comment: Sadly, this is one of those things that's easy in JavaScript and incredibly awkward in TypeScript, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259120/how-to-type-the-species-pattern-overriding-the-default-constructor-with-a-stati) (to which the answer appears to be: you can't do that).

Comment: I don't see an error here `// throws "sum() is not a function"`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - They mean at runtime: https://tsplay.dev/mxDx1m

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, I don't even consider runtime behavior answering on TS questions :D

Comment: @​Dennis - My answer appears to be incorrect (I'm glad to say), if I apply [this newly-posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328117/157247) to your code, I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJyeDm), which seems to work. Please un-accept my answer so I can delete it. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer appears to be incorrect** (I'm glad to say), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328117/157247). I'm leaving the rest of this answer intact, though, until/unless I can delete it.

---

Sadly, this is one of those things that's easy in JavaScript and incredibly awkward in TypeScript.

In JavaScript, you'd do one of two things:

- `new this.constructor(/*....*/)` as you mentioned.
- The [species pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAogHzQDeAUNNAA4BO8aqDAJtBgwLYQBc0+A2gF0A3GQrRgOCGhoBXdPBoAKNsk48w2AJ6DoAXmiCAlKTGU0ACwwQAdCs57WHCCMoBfUZQD0n6E3jIIbAByNGgAdwUAawAaaAArGSloHGRkgDNodg1NaDA0Dio0CDFaekZkFmxkMIBJbCkNYGRlJx5+AUMeCysTSi8fAAEigFoMAHNsBWRTaBpkNBkabGgqsOhumwl66Tk0BRbVCEMXaHcxCAwAL2bjcj7Z+cXljdsnaxRsMYsTs-7oCHM8BkIBYaQwIAYNFy2BYcwWSxW1VY20aqT20ESqVAkBg7HmgKYxUoYIhyCUwDASAARmBgJEeAd2OotLEMDDkAAPAD8PGwMnYVLJxl0xCp8EQyA0nXWlhgdz63n+gOBLEFMtStIWlORDWwTWgigpyzVbPMZJUTEMMzhTxlVmsqzquqaihedhsJMhhspIBpdMMxkgducYncZ2xUGgADl+YKaAgkIwsMtOQwYTAEyh0MncHyBWTiPKIPzFLdrY8EW63nMmHJmoowLEqcLiGBoABqaBU2IABmOobIZxQoTzcZg+lW0djZMzSZwij4AEZYgAmWIAZliABYOiIthAJe94GNFKOyTZi+xS-396EOQ4zzQPeCvaeWytoMRF-3FX0AHpcmQ+6HiAx6KBy1iXteQjQIqEQ0JExRAA).

Unfortunately, though, you can't do that without type assertions or outright `@ts-ignore`s in TypeScript. See [this related question about the species pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259120/how-to-type-the-species-pattern-overriding-the-default-constructor-with-a-stati), to which the answer is: you can't do that.

I think your only realistic option, if `filter` (and such) always return an instance of the class they're called on (so it's #1 above, not #2), is to do what you've done with `this` as the return type annotation, using `new this.constructor(/*...*/)` with a `@ts-ignore` on it:

```typescript
protected newInstance(items: E[]): this {
    // @ts-ignore - blech
    return new this.constructor(items);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2IQFNgBcCW8B2AeAogHzQDeAUNNAA4BO8aqDAJtBgwLYQBc0+A2gF0A3GQrRgOCGhoBXdPBoAKNsk48w2AJ6DoAXmiCAlKTGU0ACwwQAdCs57WHCCMoBfUZQD0n6E3jIIbAByNGgAdwUAawAaaAArGSloHGRkgDNodg1NaDA0Dio0CDFaekZkFmxkMIBJbCkNYGRlJx5+AUMeCysTSi8fAAEigFoMAHNsBWRTaBpkNBkabGgqsOhumwl66Tk0BRbVCEMXaHcxCAwAL2bjcj7Z+cXljdsnaxRsMYsTs-7oCHM8BkIBYaQwIAYNFy2BYcwWSxW1VY20aqT20ESqVAkBg7HmgKYxUoYIhyCUwDASAARmBgJEeAd2OotLEMDDkAAPAD8PGwMnYVLJxl0xCp8EQyA0nXWlhgdz63n+gOBLEFMtStIWlORDWwTWgigpyzVbPMZJUTEMMzhTxlVmsqzquqaihedhsJMhhspIBpdMMxkgducYncZ2xUGgADl+YKaAgkIwsMtOQwYTAEyh0MncHyBWTiPKIPzFLdrY8EW63nMmHJmoowLEqcLiGBoABqaBU2IABmOobIZxQoTzcZg+lW0djZMzSZwij4AEZYgAmWIAZliABYOiIthAJe94GNFKOyTZi+xS-396EOQ4zzQPeCvaeWytoMRF-3FX0AHpcmQ+6HiAx6KBy1iXteQjQIqEQ0JExRAA)

That correctly creates an instance of the class it's called on (even though TypeScript doesn't see the construction signature on `this.constructor`) because by default the prototype assigned to a class instance has a `constructor` property that refers to the constructor function: `this.constructor` in an instance created via `new Collection` is `Collection`; `this.constructor` in an instnace created via `new NumberCollection` is `NumberCollection`. (There are things you can do to mess that up, but `class` syntax makes it easy to avoid most of them.) So `new this.constructor(/*...*/)` creates a new object using (in the normal case) the constructor that was used to create `this`. As a result, you don't have that `sum` problem anymore; this works:

```typescript
let numbers = new NumberCollection([1, 2, 3, 4]);
console.log(numbers.sum());
const x = numbers.filter((n) => n > 1);
//    ^? −− type is NumberCollection
console.log(x.sum()); // works
```

I don't like it, but as far as I know, we're stuck with it for now.

Comment: Could you please provide more explanation why did you use `this.constructor` instead of `new Collection()` ?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - I've beefed up the paragraph above the playground link to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and comprehensive description – it works! I can live with ts-ignoring it, as it is only in one place.

Comment: It's possible to do this without type assertion via `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73328117/1674992

Answer (score 2):

To do this with type safety, use:

```js
const { constructor } = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
new constructor(...args);
```

See [Reference same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879800/reference-same-class/73328061#73328061).

Comment: Rather than cross-posting, please vote to close the other question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: That [didn't work as shown](https://tsplay.dev/mLqgkW), but [**does** work](https://tsplay.dev/wOGkpw) with `()` around everything after the `new` or similar. (I've fixed it.) Nice!! Please replace this with your full answer to the other question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, you're right - I updated again w the clearest syntax.